# boost compilation flag iw what does it mean?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

i need a file `boost_filesystem-iw-mt-gd-1_52.lib`
i know `mt == multithreading`,
gd == debug symbols
what does the flag "iw" means?

where can i find the documentation for this. i tried the boost site

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

but still nothing explains this.
is there any additional info about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR version: 
You need a `filesystem` library that was compiled using the **Intel C++ compiler** (ICC).

Long version:
The Boost [library naming convention](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) always places the toolset and version that was used to compile the library after the name of the library itself.

This means the `filesystem` lib you're looking for was compiled using the `iw` toolset. To figure out what that is, I grepped for `iw` in the [`auto_link.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/config/auto_link.hpp) source (`auto_link` is the file that auto-generates library names for platforms that support auto-linking).