# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_locale-iw-mt-1_56.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, linker, intel

I'm working on a software under VS2013, I'm trying to compile with the intel compiler and I got this error message.

Any idea ? Do we need a special version of boost ?

Comment: hav you set the library path variable?

Comment: Thanks. It works for VC++ compiler, but not when I switch to Intel Compiler. So, I don't know what is the "-iw-" name. It looks to be specific for intel compiler but I can't find any information about that !

Comment: No more idea, nobody has ever seen this library ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614221/boost-compilation-flag-iw-what-does-it-mean